how to restore to previous debugpy version in vscode
I've started using vscode 1.91.1 and docker on windows10 and WSL2 ubuntu 22.04 for about one week.
Before vscode starts showing the "there's an available update", and the workspace was single-root, I can open python project in vscode's devcontainer without problem.
After I added one more folder to the workspace to make it multi-root, and changed some setting.json file on both workspace level and project level, and reopen the workspace in devcontainer, I see new docker images are pulled to local, and devcontainere is rebuilt; while devcontainer was rebuilt, the ms-python extension was reinstalled (vscode is 1.91.1).
And now I get the following message when open the workspace in devcontainer:
[/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-linux-x64]: Extension is not compatible with Code 1.91.1. Extension requires: ^1.92.0.

I've tried change the workspace to single-root, still get this above error when reopen in devcontainer.
I've tried to remove the /root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-linux-x64 folder from WSL2 ubuntu. But it's got reinstated everytime I reopen the workspace in devcontainer.
What else should I do to restore the previous version of ms-path.debugpy extension?
(I don't want to upgrade vscode everytime there's a new version)

Why don't you want to upgrade vscode everytime? It's best for you: bug and security fixes, and as this question shows, extensions often only support recent versions.

You could open your extension store and search for the debug extension. Click the inverted triangle symbol next to uninstall. You could find a choice named "Install Another Version". You can choose the suitable version to reinstall.


If you want to disable the automatic updates. You could open your settings. Search update mode in the USER field, change it to none.

